# Is there a way to increase the padding for a border around an equation in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

Is there a way to increase the padding for a border around an equation in MS Word?

I know I can change border padding around a paragraph block, but I can't figure out how (or if it's possible) to do this with individual blocks of text - specifically, equations.  Is there a simpler way to do this than creating a specific style just for equations?

In the attached image, you can see how the border clips the last few points of the equation (i.e. the "0" in the summation is interrupted by the border). Interestingly, there's more padding at the top of the equation (i.e. the "n" in the summation is not interrupted by the border).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the number of equations which need the border is small，maybe you could try to insert the Text Box. Set No Fill and the outline color for it. Set Behind Text as Wrap Text. At last adjust its size and move it to your equation. But the test box won’t move with the equation. If you move the equation and you might move the text box manually.

[image]

Comment: What if you put each paragraph in a table cell then you can adjust the borders/space for the table instead?